# Why isn't this 'if' statement working?

Tags: python, passwords

I have created an if statement in Python, it is a password strength checker. I think it might be the numbers, but I have no clue.

When I type in; aabbcc3 
it is meant to be MEDIUM, but it comes up with WEAK. Same as RTH14hl as it comes up with MEDIUM but it's meant to be STRONG.

```
if u >=6 or l >=6 or n >=6:
    print("weak")

elif u > 1 and n > 1:
    print("medium")

elif l > 3 and n >= 1:
    print("medium")

elif u > 1 and l> 1:
    print("medium")

elif u > 3 and l >  2 and nums > 2: 
    print("strong")
```

Comment: What is `u`, `l` and `n`?

Comment: upper, lower and numbers. upper has the amount of uppercase letters in the password, lowercase has the amount of lowercase, and numbers is the amount of numbers

Comment: The users enters their password, all the lowercase, uppercase and numeric characters are counted. It then uses ifs to ask if they are weak or medium or strong

Comment: `u = 4; l = 3; n = 3` means `u > 1 and l > 1` is True. So is `u > 1 and n > 1`. That means for those value it'll print `medium` even though that *also* fits the criteria for `strong`. You need to rethink your logic here.

Comment: Can you show us how you determine the values of u, l and n based on the input string.

Comment: I'm only going to have to do a short piece, as it is quit large

Comment: `u = p.count("A") + p.count("B") + p.count("C")`, `l = p.count("a") + p.count("b") + p.count("c")`, `n =  p.count("1") + p.count("2") + p.count("3")`, there is way more going all through the alphabet

Comment: @user2816683 Ok you can definitely simplify this. `u = sum([int(c.islower()) for c in p])` check as well `isupper()` and `isnumeric()`

Comment: I think that there are much better ways generating all the `u`, `l` and `n` variables. Maybe edit that into your question and I'll edit a better way of doing it into my answer.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that the order in which the statements are set up is producing an effect that you do not want. For example:

```
elif u > 1 and l> 1:
    print("medium")

elif u > 3 and l >  2 and nums > 2: 
    print("strong")
```

The last line here will never be executed. Because anything that makes the last conditional true will make the previous conditional be true.

For example if u is 4 and l is 4 then:

```
elif u > 1 and l> 1:
```

becomes:

```
elif 4 > 1 and 4 > 1:
```

which will evaluate to `True` and print "medium"

You can solve this issue by rearranging the order of the statements like so:

```
elif u > 3 and l >  2 and nums > 2: 
    print("strong")

elif u > 1 and l> 1:
    print("medium")
```

Essentially you want the hardest things to match be at the top then let non matches fall down to easier to match cases, not the other way around.

Also from the comment made I think it's highly likely that you probably want to generate the `u` `l` and `n` values differently to how you currently are doing it. Python has a nice feature called [generator expressions](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) that along with some  library function will make your code much more maintainable.

Instead of:

```
u = p.count("A") + p.count("B") + p.count("C"), ...
l = p.count("a") + p.count("b") + p.count("c"), ...
n = p.count("1") + p.count("2") + p.count("3"), ...
```

you can do:

```
u = sum((char.isalpha() for char in p))
l = sum((char.islower() for char in p))
n = sum((char.isdigit() for char in p))
```